# WordPress image path/link gets changed or broken

Tags: wordpress, image, wordpress-theming, filepath

This is the code When I upload an image by "Add media" button.

```
<p><a href="http://bebe15594.staging-cloud.partnerconsole.net/wp-content/uploads/Brains-like-a-pack-of-cards-Card-Placeholder.png"><img class="alignleft wp-image-197 size-full" src="http://bebe15594.staging-cloud.partnerconsole.net/wp-content/uploads/Brains-like-a-pack-of-cards-Card-Placeholder.png" alt="Brains like a pack of cards - Card Placeholder" width="470" height="663" /></a></p>
```

But when I save/update the above code changes to

```
<p><a href="\&quot;http://bebe15594.staging-cloud.partnerconsole.net/wp-content/uploads/Brains-like-a-pack-of-cards-Card-Placeholder.png\&quot;"><img class="\&quot;alignleft" src="\&quot;http://bebe15594.staging-cloud.partnerconsole.net/wp-content/uploads/Brains-like-a-pack-of-cards-Card-Placeholder.png\&quot;" alt="\&quot;Brains" width="\&quot;470\&quot;" height="\&quot;663\&quot;" /></a></p>
```

Can anyone tell me why it's acting like this?
what can I do to fix this problem??

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your functions.php file:

```
 function wpse72941_content_filter( $content ) {
   $new_content = '';
   foreach( preg_split( '/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/', $content ) as $line ) {
   $new_content .= preg_replace( '/^&gt;/', '>', $line ) . '\r\n';
   }
   return $new_content;
 }
 add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse72941_content_filter', 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify where your line of code is, i.e. a custom template, the normal 'add post' page, etc. If it's a custom template, add `wp_print_scripts('media-upload');` before you enque your own script/s, and after `wp_enque_script('jquery');`. This is assuming you are using wp_editor to upload the images.